# Ubuntu 16.04 Menu Bar and Application/Side Bar Missing

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher, compiz

Here's what I've tried with no luck-

```
Unity --reset
The --reset option is deprecated, You should run with no options instead.
unity-panel-service stop/waiting
unity7 stop/waiting
unity-panel-service start/running, process 5248
unity7 start/running, process 5307


unity --replace
WARNING: This is for compatibility with other desktop interfaces please use unity without --replace
unity-panel-service stop/waiting
unity7 stop/waiting
unity-panel-service start/running, process 5092
unity7 start/running, process 5151

export DISPLAY=:0 sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ setsid unity

unity-panel-service stop/waiting
unity7 stop/waiting
unity-panel-service start/running, process 5598
unity7 start/running, process 5709
```

Have done the whole ccsm, enable Ubuntu unity plugin (along with all the rest of the things that need to be enabled with it). Does not show the menu/side bars once I enable it, nor on reboot, and seems to not stay enabled after reboot.

Additionally, I've seen suggested creating a new administrator account. I've done that.. THAT account does have the menu/side bar. I don't know what that means or how that helps fix this account.

I've tried screen resolutions. No luck fixing it.

I've tried installing/reinstalling indicators. No luck fixing it.

What else could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
unity --reset-icons
```